# Screen Sharing between iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, networking

I want to share the screen between two iPhone using local network but unfortunately i have not seen any tutorial or help from any where can anyone guide how can I implement this?

The scenario is as follows:

I have installed my Application on two iPhones: iPhoneA and iPhoneB. iPhoneA is act like Server and send the request to iPhoneB to share it's screen as iPhoneB accept the request the screen of iPhoneB will start monitoring on iPhoneA. iPhoneA can only view the screen, and cannot do anything else.

Comment: Cool. Be sure to ask questions here when you have some... [FAQ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas as starting point,

1. You could look into AirPlay ability. You can easily share your iPhone screen with a Mac connected screen using AirPlay, maybe that could be used to do it between two iPhones?
2. There was an app for streaming music similar to AirPlay (whose name I can't remember) Maybe that could help
3. ZeroC Ice framework can be used for streaming. I've managed to get it to work for Android but have no experience with their iOS product [Ice Touch](http://www.zeroc.com/icetouch/index.html)